# Fortran last element of the array

Tags: arrays, fortran

Can I write the last element of an array 'A' as A(-1) in Fortan 90 or 95 like we do in python? If not what can be the way of writing the last element other than writing with the last index A(N), where N is last index value.

Comment: Though A(-1) does not work, I guess we can make (mimic) a periodic array using [modulo](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/gfortran/MODULO.html). For example, if `A` is declared as `A(0:N-1) `(i.e. 0-based), `A(modulo(i, N))` becomes periodic for any `i` (even negative). If `B` is declared as `B(1:N)` (i.e. 1-based), we need to shift the index by one so `B(modulo(i-1, N) + 1)` (hope this is correct...)

Comment: I don't think it would work, suppose I have to find
    `real :: u(0:N)`
    `do i=0,N`
    `∇u = (u(i-1)-2*u(i)+u(i+1))/h**2`
    `end do`
Now at `i=0` , I need `u(i-1)=u(N)` for periodic boundary and it's not possible to have `u(-1)` as last element in fortran even if some how get -1 using modulo.

Comment: modulo(i,N) converts i to within [0,N-1], so what I've written above is to use such a conversion function for indices (whatever it is). But for finite-difference calculations etc, I think a better (more efficient) approach would be to treat the boundary separately so that there is no overhead from the use of such index function (and make the memory access more straightforward). On the other hand, if the access of a periodic array is not a bottleneck (e.g., a container of large objects), I guess indexing functions could be useful.

Comment: From OP's comment on the answer: *I asked this question because I wanted to use it for periodic boundary condition*  So this is an example of an XY Problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  If OP wants to know how to implement periodic boundary conditions in Fortran, that's a different, and much more interesting, question.

Comment: @roygvib, Yeah this is what I am doing treating boundary separately and applying periodic boundary condition on them. I am using mod function for `N`  `mod(i,N)`. When `i` reaches `N` it gives me zero (initial value of i). I just have to treat boundary at i=0 separately.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, thanks I would keep that in mind for next time by not asking xy problem.

Comment: @ManuGupta To make sure, mod() and modulo() are different functions (only the latter is a periodic function). Just for fun, for u(0:N), I think it will be interesting to print the value of modulo(i,N+1) for i = -2,-1,...,N,N+1, etc (which falls within 0:N periodically, unlike mod(i,N)). But in practice, treating the boundary separately is probably simpler and better... Good luck :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you may not. You will be writing to a memory location which may be another variable or other important bit of information and you have no way of knowing the result.

If you do not have N, you can use the size() function.

```
A(size(A)) = ......
```

Edit: Fortran also has Lbound() and Ubound() functions when custom array bounds have been declared. Using Ubound() always returns the upper bound of the Array while size() will work for Fortran standard arrays that begin with index 1. Lbound() and Ubound, however, return arrays unless a dimension parameter is added. For a 1-dimensional array, there is only dimension #1 so this will always work to access the last element in a 1-Dimensional array.

```
A(Ubound(A,1)) = ......
```

Comment: It may be a little more complicated than this.  Consider an array declaration such as `integer :: a(-5,5)` for which (i) `a(-1)` refers to the 5th element, and (ii) `size(a)-1` returns `10`.  Worth knowing about `ubound` and `lbound`.

Comment: Downvote from me. Not only does this not consider declarations with custom bounds, but it is based on 0-indexed arrays, which is not the fortran default.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. A more complete answer has been edited in. Note that the questions is tagged Fortran90 and these functions are for 95 and later.

Comment: No, that will not work, ubound returns an array if called like this. Besides, I am pretty sure it was available in Fortran 90 already and even if not, the question says 90 or 95 anyway. Removed the confusing tag.

Comment: Thanks, all I asked this question because I wanted to use it for periodic boundary condition like I do in python:- 
    `[i][(i-1)%I],   [i][(i+1)%I]`

Comment: Here,
    `(i-1)%I` gives me -1 for i=0 and A(-1) is the last element in python, but now it's clear to me that I can't do like this in fortran.